# I don't know how to manage my classes sturctures with SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2, roguelike

I try to create some C++ "rogue-like" game with SDL-2. For this I followed the Lazy foo's tutorial to understand how work with SDL.

I've studied C++/C# for 3 year but now I study project management and don't have no more IT courses...

Here's the github for the code : https://github.com/Paingouin/Roguelike-SDL2-train/tree/master/

I created 2 class : `LTexture` to help managing loading and rendering of a picture and `Glyph` to manage the animation/scaling and the positioning of the picture...

Now, I wanted create a Entity class, composed of a `Glyph` Object, which I would use to represent a Wall, a monster, an item etc... but, I think if I do that I will use too much memory...

Maybe I should use an aggregation by initialize an Array of pointer of Glyph and associate it to my Entity's object... I don't know,  I'm lost...

Can you help me? And, have you any tips or advice to help me structuring correctly?

Comment: see this book https://www.amazon.com/SDL-Game-Development-Black-White/dp/1849696829. You will see how to create and manage classes for games.

Comment: Thanks ! I've see that there's a lot of programming book with SDL but this one looks good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually your question can be answered without reffering directly to SDL and same issue may arise with any library(like sfml) and the solution is all about the same:
the answer is the singleton design pattern
since your texture why i say singleton?
let's talk about the wall tile. you might have thousands or even more wall tiles
all have the **same** texture, do you really want to load it time and time agan per each wall? no. it's the same texture, you want to have **one instance** of each given texture, even more: you can save resource work if you use sprite sheet that contains EVERYTHING or have let's say 3 sheets: here's an example in sfml though the idea should be the same in SDL.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

here's an sfml implementation but the idea behind it should be clear and easy to immitate:

```
class Resources {
 sf::Clock m_clock; //holds clock
 sf::Texture m_soma,m_lvl,m_enemies; //holds hero,lvl &enemies textures respectively
 sf::Font m_font; //holds game font
 Resources();
public:

 ~Resources() {}
 Resources(const Resources &) = delete;
 Resources& operator=(const Resources &) = delete;


 static Resources& instance();
 sf::Texture& texture();
 sf::Texture& lvlTexture();
 sf::Texture& Enemies();
 sf::Clock& clock();
 sf::Font & Font();
};
```

cpp file: notice i could use a vector instead of 3 textures

```
Resources::Resources()
{
  //loading textures(hero,lvls,enemies)
   if (!m_soma.loadFromFile("..\\resources\\sprites\\soma.png"))
   {
       std::cerr << "problem loading texture\n";
       throw ResourceExceptions("couldn't load player sprites!: must have    ..\\resources\\sprites\\soma.png");
   }

   if (!m_lvl.loadFromFile("..\\resources\\sprites\\lv.png"))
   {
    std::cerr << "problem loading texture\n";
    throw ResourceExceptions("couldn't load level sprites!: must have ..\\resources\\sprites\\lv.png");
   }

   if (!m_enemies.loadFromFile("..\\resources\\sprites\\enemies.png"))
   {
       std::cerr << "problem loading texture\n";
       throw ResourceExceptions("couldn't load enemies sprites!: must have ..\\resources\\sprites\\enemies.png");
   }
 //loading font once
   if (!m_font.loadFromFile("..\\resources\\font\\gothic.otf"))
   {
       std::cerr << "problem loading font\n";
       throw ResourceExceptions("couldn't load game Font: must have ..\\resources\\font\\gothic.otf");
   }

 }

 Resources & Resources::instance()
 {
    static Resources resource;
    return resource;
 }

sf::Texture & Resources::texture()
{
    return m_soma;
}

sf::Texture & Resources::lvlTexture()
{
     return m_lvl;
}

sf::Texture & Resources::Enemies()
{
     return m_enemies;
}

sf::Clock & Resources::clock()
{
    return m_clock;
}

sf::Font & Resources::Font()
{
  return m_font;
}
```

eg. of usage would be: 
    m_sprite.setTexture(Resources::instance().texture());

//---------------------------------------

same idea can be applied anywhere, even more, if by a chance you'll deal with 3d objects and will render those you'll find that singleton isn't even enough there and you can refer to the "flyweight" design patters
overall i suggest you to read two things:
gameprogrammingpatterns.com
and the legendary book: Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software

there're several code issues that exist in your code:
eg. the switch case on movement. ask yourself this "what happens if suddenly i want to add an extra action?" "what if for eg. i want it to behave differently according to the previous movement?" your approach will carry you to extensive and LONG switch cases. both will show you ways that will allow you to change code more easily

Comment: Wow Thanks! I didn't know about the singleton pattern! This kind of structure will help me a LOT!   I've see that the switch is a problem ( I hate switch but It made things easier to start) ...  And thanks for the books suggestion!

Comment: more design patterns that are EXTREMELY useful in game designs are: strategy(eg. defining various enemy behaviours), state pattern (to avoid stuff like jumping and duckin at the same time or switch between menus) even command can help you alot, those books are not neceserally to be read from cover to cover but i do suggest you do, it will augment your programming skills by milestones.